# WPF Prism InteractionRequestTrigger: Re-create View and ViewModel upon show

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

When using InteractionRequestTrigger for showing a custom popup view, the same instances of the View and ViewModel will be used each time it's shown. How can I recreate/reset the View/ViewModel, so the state of the View is "as default". The problem is that I use a TabControl in my popup, and the last selected tab is still selected after I close and reopen the popup.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is method that won't require you to create a new set of nuts and bolts.

1. Implement `IInteractionRequestAware`on your view model.
2. Create a integer property on the view model to store the index of the selected tab
3. Bind `TabControl.SelectedIndex` to the new property
4. In the implementation of the `IInteractionRequestAware.Notification` setter, reset the selected index property to 0.

Comment: Thanks, this was for me the quickest way of solving it at the moment

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own PopupWindowAction.  Add a property for the WindowContent Type and use that to create the new instance every time you show the popup.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I will have this solution in my mind as well